# Android 'Install App' missing for PWA and 'beforeinstallprompt' not fired

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, a2hs

I have a PWA with all the requirements to install it to devices. This PWA is being used by multiple people and always installed without any problems. Now I have a customer who bought 3 new identical  android devices and on 2 devices the installation went smoothly. But on one device the 'Install PWA' option is missing and the 'beforeinstallprompt' is never fired.

I have already tried to:

- Reset device to factory settings
- Update the device to latest version
- Reinstalled Google Chrome
- Update Google Chrome to the latest version
- Change the chrome://flags to allow PWA installing

So far no luck.

I have added screenshots of 2 sites that should demo the installation of PWA's. I am also unable to install these demo PWA's since the 'Install App' is missing and the 'beforeinstallprompt' is never fired. On all of the other devices I have at hand these demo PWA's are installable.
I tried the folowing demo projects:

- https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/
  Referenced by:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen

and:

- https://mlearn-pwa-web-app-install-prompt.glitch.me/

[SCREENSHOT1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ibMZ.png)
[SCREENSHOT2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX3JV.png)

Comment: Whats the make and model for the device having the issue?